# CSS "background-position: bottom" Imperfect on Mobile Browsers

Tags: html, css, web

```css
body
{
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/Aurigids_-_Jeremie_Vaubaillon.jpg/1280px-Aurigids_-_Jeremie_Vaubaillon.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

a
{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a>Hello, world!</a>
```

A site I'm developing has a background-image that fills the viewport and is anchored to the bottom.  It works perfectly on PC, but mobile browsers on Android anchor the background-image to the bottom of the last element if the content doesn't fill the screen, leaving a blank space below it.  How can I fix this to make the background-image correctly fill the screen on Android?

Comment: Are you sure about that? If another user confirms this, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

A friend helped me solve this. The body was smaller than the viewport, leaving the blank space.  I moved the background properties to the html selector and added "height: 100%;" as seen in this new code sample.

```css
html
{
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/Aurigids_-_Jeremie_Vaubaillon.jpg/1280px-Aurigids_-_Jeremie_Vaubaillon.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

a
{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a>Hello, world!</a>
```